# Django : Update fields from lookup in a single .update() call

Tags: django, field, lookup

I'd like to know if there's a way to perform a batch update of a field in a model with a value from a lookup.

Assume this model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField(... field params here ...)
    ... more fields here ...

class ShopcartProductEntry(models.Model):
    oncommit_price = models.DecimalField(
        ... field params here, similar to price params ...)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(... field params, doesn't matter here ...)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=False)
    shopcart = models.ForeignKey(
                   Shopcart, null=False, related_name='entries', ... more params ...)

class Shopcart(models.Model):
    ... fields here ...

    def commit(self):
        pass #my question will come in this method
```

As the doc says, if i write:

```
    def commit(self):
        self.entries.update(oncommit_price=F('product__price'))
```

Django will cry. How can i do that query? Currently I iterate over each entry. I don't like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a last resort you can always write your own SQL `UPDATE` query:

```
sql = ''' UPDATE myapp_shopcartproductentry SPE
          JOIN myapp_product P ON P.id = SPE.product_id
          SET SPE.oncommit_price = P.price
          WHERE SPE.shopcart_id = %s '''
```

And then execute it directly using a [custom SQL transaction](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly):

```
def commit(self):
    sql = ''' ... SQL as above ... '''
    from django.db import connection, transaction
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql, [self.id])
    transaction.commit_unless_managed()
```

Comment: thank you. stackoverflow never notified me that answer. better late than never :p. bookmarking this page...